# How do I place buttons next to each other, sticking them, in Android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am new to Android UI and I am trying to build a UI like this - 
The problem I am facing is positioning the buttons like this.[image: UI Wireframe]

Comment: Where is the code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put your button in center you need to use **`android:layout_gravity="center"`**

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/linear_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Login" />

    <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Sign Up" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> drawable/linear_bg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#3F51B5" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. And is completely diff from what I was approaching.

Comment: @nkirit welcome happy to help, please let me know if you have any query

Answer (score 1):

Make 2 files in your drawables folder

```
left_round


<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"></solid>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"></corners>

right_round


<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"></solid>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"></corners>
```

and apply to your both buttons like this

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Login"
                    android:background="@drawable/left_round" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Sign Up"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/right_round" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Constraint layout. Here is an example.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/leftcornerround"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"

    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Log In"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rightcornerround"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Sign Up"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline" />
```

create two drawable file for background

1) leftcornerround.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"></solid>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
       android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"
       android:topRightRadius="0dp"
       android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

2) rightcornerround.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"></solid>
     <corners android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="12dp"
       android:bottomRightRadius="12dp"/>
 </shape>
```